# Enabling publishing infrastructure feature by default in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: publishing-site, publishing, site-settings, settings

I saw this question posted on a site and I would like to know if there is an answer as I have the same issue.

I know how to in the settings activate publishing feature on a site but is it possible to have this by default when a new site is created from the UI?

I have some customized stylesheets and when a new team site is created it doesn't load these but instead looks like a sharepoint site out of the box. When I go to settings and activate publishing features the page reloads with the custom stylesheets. I wish to not have to do this every time a new site is created. Is there a solution to this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928989/enabling-publishing-infrastructure-feature-by-default-in-sharepoint-2010

I would like to know if there is an OOTB or designer solution 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463479.aspx) you have ["Web Site Creation or Deletion Events"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463479.aspx)

You will notice the way to do this is with [feature association](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544294.aspx).